# Three.JS: Get position along direction vector

Tags: three.js

I have a position vector:

```
var startPos = new THREE.Vector3(1.2, -2.34, 0.5);
```

A direction vector:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0.657873735, -0.2497291683, 0.71051916);
```

And a distance:

```
var distance = 1;
```

How to calculate a new position vector, starting from `startPos` that is moved the `distance` along the `direction`?

Comment: pos = start + distance * direction

Comment: and don't forget to normalize the direction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var startPos = new THREE.Vector3(1.2, -2.34, 0.5);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0.6578737359955765, -0.24972916834682138, 0.710519166466616);
var distance = 1;

var newPos = new THREE.Vector3();
newPos.addVectors ( startPos, direction.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
```